# com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar with viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use the library: com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar with the ViewPager but It gives a nullpointerexception when I try to add it into the viewpager. But when I use it outside the ViewPager there is no problem. And fragments are no option because you cannot nest fragments in a viewpager that is in a fragment.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/ll_filter_seekbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">


                <com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar
                    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/rangebar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    custom:tickCount="2000"
                    custom:tickHeight="0dp" />


      </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar.onDraw(RangeBar.java:265)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2171)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1603)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:584)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:338)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:560)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:622)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:585)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:527)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:522)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The code from the PageAdapter:

```
public class FilterPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 1;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_PAGES;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    int resId = 0;
    Tools.LOG_DEBUG("This page: " + position);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.id.page_one;
            break;
    }
    return container.findViewById(resId);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}
}
```

Comment: You add views to the `ViewPager` through its adapter and not directly in the xml layout.

Comment: @Luksprog I added the code from the PageAdapter to the question. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Not really. Remove the `LinearLayout` from the xml you posted, that isn't supposed to be there. Then, in the adapter's `instantiateItem()` method, for position 0 get a reference to the `LayoutInflater`(you'll need to pass the `Context` in the adapter) and inflate and return a xml layout that holds the previously removed `LinearLayout`(along with the range bar).

Comment: @Luksprog Ok I will change that when I get home in have an hour

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks that works. If you give it as an answer I will approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ViewPager` adds its children(the pages) through it's adapter, you shouldn't add the child views directly in the xml layout as you did. So, keep the initial layout with only the `ViewPager`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

create a new xml layout with the content of the page(like `page.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/ll_filter_seekbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">


            <com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/rangebar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                custom:tickCount="2000"
                custom:tickHeight="0dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and wire this up in the adapter by getting a reference to a `LayoutInflater`(either pass it to the adapter directly or create it from a `Context`)and then using that to inflate the above `page.xml` layout according to your position.